# Ускорить алгоритм нахождения для каждого числа ближайшего большего правого соседа

Tags: c++, алгоритм

доброго времени суток всем. собственно столкнулся с проблемой. программа работает, но некоторые тесты не проходят по времени. уже не знаю что и как упростить. кому интересно, то сама задача вот[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
код вот

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file1("input.txt");
    int n;
    file1 >> n;
    int *b = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        file1 >> b[i];
    }
    file1.close();
    std::ofstream file2("output.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int j = i + 1;
        while (b[j] <= b[i] && j < n) ++j;
         j < n? file2 << b[j] << " ":file2 << b[i] << " ";
    }
    delete(b);
    file2.close();
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, напишите условие задачи текстом, вместо добавления его картинкой.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Приведённый код использует алгоритм, квадратичный от числа элементов.
Однако с использованием структуры данных "стек" можно обойтись линейным проходом.

В стеке лежат индексы небитых на текущий момент элементов.
Если очередной элемент больше последних в стеке,  он их "бьёт" - их индексы извлекаются из стека и элементы в соответствующих позициях заменяются на очередной. Его индекс помещается в стек.

Код на Delphi для демонстрации принципа:

```
   var A := [2, 5, 3, 7, 4, 3, 2, 8, 1];

   var St := TStack<Integer>.Create;
   for var i := 0 to High(A) do begin
       Writeln(i, A[i]:5);
       while (St.Count > 0) and (A[St.Peek] < A[i]) do
          A[St.Pop] := A[i];
       St.Push(i);
   end;

   Writeln('----------');
   for var i := 0 to High(A) do
       Writeln(i, A[i]:5);

0    2
1    5
2    3
3    7
4    4
5    3
6    2
7    8
8    1
-------
0    5
1    7
2    7
3    8
4    8
5    8
6    8
7    8
8    1
```